# How to personalize index when building array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Good day,

Junior PHP guy here, I am trying to build an array from an answer back from web service.

The answer back from web service provide an xml response as such.

```
<links>
<link rel="self" href="https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment/347881315405043891" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link>
<link rel="details" href="https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment/347881315405043891/details" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link>
<link rel="group" href="https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment?groupid=bobo" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link>
<link rel="price" href="https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment/347881315405043891/price" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link>
<link rel="label" href="https://XX/ers/artifact/11111111/5555555/0" media-type="application/pdf" index="0"></link>
</links>
```

I am trying to build an array out of the xml

```
foreach ($shipment->{'links'}->{'link'} as $link) {
//for each shipment go throught the loop and build array
$array[] = $link->attributes()->{'rel'};
//$array[] = $link->attributes()->{'href'};
}   
print_r($array);
```

WHICH OUTPUTS

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => self ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => details ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => group ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => price ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => label ) )
```

Ideally How would i make the key the "rel=" so that in my if statement I could actually use the keyword instead of a number?

//if the elementid in the array exist do the action

```
if (array_key_exists("4", $array)) {
//grab the elementid label and parse it to grab image id from the url
$parts = Explode('/', $array[4]);
$label = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```

//echo $label;

```
}

if (array_key_exists("5", $array)) {
```

//grab the elementid returnlabeland parse it to grab image id from the url

```
$parts = Explode('/', $array[5]);
$returnlabel = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```

//echo $returnlabel;

```
}
```

Comment: How do you get the keyword?  And what is the purpose of the big block of code after your question?

Comment: The xml <links>
<link **rel="self"** **href="**https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment/347881315405043891" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link> or <link **rel="details"** **href=**"https://XX/rs/111111111/2222222222/shipment/347881315405043891/details" media-type="application/vnd.cpc.shipment-v4+xml"></link>. How to build array with these being key and have the value for each key to url so look like this myarray = [self=>https://xxxxx.com, price=>https://xxxx.com];

Comment: the block of code after is my condition as is now, it look at the array and for index 1 do this, for index 2 do this. I would prefer if index self do this, if index details do this. It parse the string in href and capture image id in this case "12345/0" capture "12345" from url. Ideally I would prefer refering to self instead of 1 and details insread of 2 in my conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array['rel'] = $link->attributes()->{'rel'};
```

If you use the shortcut `[]` notation, PHP will simply use the next higher unused numeric index available to create the new array element. If you want something other than that next-in-sequence number, you'll have to supply it yourself.

Note that as-written, the above code will simply overwrite the previous iteration's rel with the current iterations.

---

comment followup

Ok, you'd want something like this, instead:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($shipment->{'links'}->{'link'} as $link) {
    $rel = $link->getAttribute('rel');
    $array[$rel][] = $link;
}
```

Then later on you can do something like:

```
foreach ($array['self'] as $link) {
   $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
   ... do something with the href ...
}
```

Comment: How would i achieve this? is ther enough info in my question? ideally it would accomodate my if sdtatement to say if self exist then do this if details exist then do this. How to build array correctly so key index contain these keywords instead of numbers. the keyword are from the xml where rel=self is the keyword

Comment: ah. you want to end up with `$array['self']`, `$array['details']`, etc..., each of which contains all of the links of that group?

Comment: one array inside having self with value of href from the xml. $myarray['self'=>https://www.sdsds.self.com, ['details'=>https://www.sdsds.details.com]. So my if condition I can use self or details if exist

Comment: I simply want to convert the xml above to an array. the array will contain each links returned which are identified as self,detail,price,artefact and each of these url will have a value that is from the xml also which is href=https://xxxxxxxx then I can make a condition like if (array_key_exists("self", $array)) {.....

Comment: can i do this? Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [self] => https://www.qwerty.com )

Answer (score 0):

Good day, i tinkered around and figured it out, this was a great exercise, thank you for the tip that helped me understand a few things

foreach ($shipment->{'links'}->{'link'} as $link) {
                                    $array = current($link->attributes());

```
                                foreach ($array as $attributes => $value) {
                                    //echo $attributes => $value;
                                    "$attributes => $value";
                                }
                                if (in_array("self", $array)) {
                                    echo "Got self";
                                    $array['href'];
                                    $parts = Explode('/', $array['href']);
                                    $shipmentid = $parts[count($parts) - 1];
                                    echo $shipmentid;
                                }


                                if (in_array("details", $array)) {
                                    echo "Got details";
                                    $parts = Explode('/', $array['href']);
                                    $shipmentdetails = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
                                    echo $shipmentdetails;
                                }

                                if (in_array("price", $array)) {
                                    echo "Got price";
                                    $parts = Explode('/', $array['href']);
                                    $shipmentprice = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
                                    echo $shipmentprice;
                                }


                                if (in_array("label", $array)) {
                                    echo "Got labelId";
                                    $parts = Explode('/', $array['href']);
                                    $shipmentartifact = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
                                    echo $shipmentartifact;
                                }


                                  if (in_array("returnLabel", $array)) {
                                    echo "Got returnlabelId";
                                    $parts = Explode('/', $array['href']);
                                    $returnlabel = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
                                    echo $returnlabel;
                                }   

                                echo '<pre>';
                                print_r($array);
                                echo '</pre>';

                            }
                        }


                                echo '<form action="GetShipment.php" method="GET"><input type="hidden" name="shipmentid" value="' . $shipmentid . '"/><input type="submit" value="Get Shipment" /></form>';
                                echo '<form action="/../GetShipmentDetails/GetShipmentDetails.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="shipmentdetails" value="' . $shipmentdetails . '"/><input type="submit" value="Get Shipment Details" /></form>';
                                echo '<form action="/../GetShipmentPrice/GetShipmentPrice.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="shipmentprice" value="' . $shipmentprice . '"/><input type="submit" value="Get Shipment Price" /></form>';
                                echo '<form action="/../GetShipmentArtifact/GetShipmentArtifact.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="shipmentartifact" value="' . $shipmentartifact . '"/><input type="submit" name="artifactidfake" value="Print Shipping label"/></form>';
                                echo '<form action="/../GetShipmentArtifact/GetShipmentArtifact.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="returnlabel" value="' . $returnlabel . '"/><input type="submit" name="artifactidfake" value="Return Shipping label/Commercial invoice "/></form></td>';
                                echo '<form action="/../VoidShipment/VoidShipment.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="shipmentid" value="' . $shipment->{'shipment-id'} . '"/><input type="submit" name="Try me" value="Void Shipment" /></form></td>';
```